# cite an existing equation into a reference

Tags: citing, back-referencing

I have a problem into citing an equation that exists on a book, I have referenced the book at the end of my tex as an bibitem (for ex: `\bibitem{book}...`), but I want to specify that an equation number 3.11 in this book was used. Like that :
[2/3.11]

Please help me I can not figure out this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The best way to achieve your objective depends importantly on whether or not you're loading citation-related packages, such as `cite`, `natbib`, and `biblatex`. Please indicate if you use any such packages.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
\cite[equation 3.11]{book}
```

to add `equation 3.11` or any other form of additional text to the text generated from the `book` key in the bibliography.

Comment: Depending on how you want to format your citation, you can either use `\cite[suffix]{bibtexkey}`, or `\cite[prefix][suffix]{bibtexkey}`. (Note that in the latter command, `suffix` can be empty if you only want a `prefix`.) See e.g. the [Reference sheet for natbib usage](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php?lang=en) for more info and examples if you use `natbib`.